# what's the best practice for pooling Hive JDBC connections

Tags: jdbc, hadoop, connection-pooling, hive, hdfs

I am using Hive JDBC driver to do sql like query against my HDFS data store. I've been trying to use c3p0 to handle the connection pooling. I am not so sure it's the right approach since Hive query can be taking quite long time sometimes which means the connection will be held for quite long not being released back to the pool, I am struggling to think of a right setting number for max number of connections in c3p0 configuration as well.

Is there any best practice for pooling the hive jdbc connection? c3p0? DBCP?

How about MAX_POOL_SIZE? Should it be bigger than normal setting for RDB ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oh great, so the question in the thread you mention was actually asked by me a long ago :)
It'd be interesting to see how to use that in your use case.

But let me tell you Hive launches Hadoop jobs whenever required depending upon you query.
So, if you want to execute multiple queries, which I believe is what you want to do here, you need to use a job scheduler that can run multiple jobs concurrently. Hadoop by default uses  **first-in-first-out(FIFO) scheduler**, pulling jobs from a work queue. So, would like to switch to Fair scheduler or Capacity scheduler.

The core idea behind the fair share scheduler was to assign resources to jobs such that on average over time, each job gets an equal share of the available resources.

The capacity scheduler shares some of the principles of the fair scheduler but has distinct differences, too. First, capacity scheduling was defined for large clusters, which may have multiple, independent consumers and target applications.In capacity scheduling, instead of pools, several queues are created, each with a configurable number of map and reduce slots. Each queue is also assigned a guaranteed capacity (where the overall capacity of the cluster is the sum of each queue's capacity). Second, ability to prioritize jobs within a queue. Lastly, is the presence of strict access controls on queues.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I am still a bit confused here, If I am pooling 10 JDBC connections to Hive, does that mean I opened up 10 hive jobs in parallel? What happens to it once the job is done? that jdbc connection is released back to the pool? Next time a new query will take a jdbc connection and have a new hive job ? what benefit I gain then by using jdbc connection pooling here, only just the creation/deletion of the jdbc connections?

Comment: What I've understood so far is that, you can open multiple connection to MySql or whatever DBMS used by Hive as a metastore but, bottom line is that, when you fire complex queries, hive will in turn create MapReduce jobs to fetch the result from Hive warehouse, which in your case is in HDFS.

Comment: Continuing...Pooling I used was kind of like threads. I reserved say 10 threads connection to hive a server, depending upon the capacity of my cluster. A query say, 'select name from employee' would consume one thread. Another such query, would say, occupy one more thread and so on. When a query finishes, I would return (checkin) the thread, associated with that query, back to the pool of threads.

Comment: By the way, you accepted your own answer? I have never seen that happen earlier. :D

Comment: yeah, that was before your comment showed up,now you deserve the green tic:) So you are not pooling the jdbc connections to the metastore?

Comment: Continuing...By looking into the HiveConnection source code, I got the feeling that, as long as I use DBCP or C3P0 to pool my jdbc connection to Hive Metastore, It will work just like what u described above. How did you achieve the pooling you mentioned above? Can you point me a direction. Thanks a lot ^^

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9929/discussion-between-shengjie-and-jtherocker)